# Multiple OneToOne relation with TypeOrm doesn't work

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm, one-to-one

I currently using NestJS 8.4.7 and TypeORM 0.3.10

I want to make two (or more) OneToOne relations in my entity class based on an **existing SQL Database**

Here is my code :

```js
// Article Entity    
@Entity({ name: 'node' })
    export class Article {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
      public articleId: number
      
 

 @OneToOne(() => ArticleBody)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'articleId', referencedColumnName: 'bodyId' })
  public body: ArticleBody

  @OneToOne(() => ArticleTitle)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'articleId', referencedColumnName: 'titleId' })
  public title: ArticleTitle
    }

// Body Entity
@Entity({ name: 'article_body' })
export class ArticleBody {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public bodyId: number

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public bodyValue: string

}

// Title Entity
@Entity({ name: 'article_title' })
export class ArticleTitle {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public titleId: number

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public titleValue: string

}
```

And I have this error:

```
 sqlMessage: ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown column 'Article__Article_body.titleId' in 'on clause'
```

```sql
sql: SELECT
    `Article`.`articleId` AS `Article_nid`,
    `Article__Article_body`.`bodyValue` AS `Article__Article_body_bodyValue`,
    `Article__Article_title`.`titleValue` AS `Article__Article_title_titleValue`
FROM `Article` `Article`
    LEFT JOIN `article_body` `Article__Article_body` ON Article__Article_body.titleId=`Article`.`articleId`
    LEFT JOIN `article_title` `Article__Article_title` ON `Article__Article_title`.`titleId`=`Article`.`articleId`
WHERE (`Article`.`articleId` = 1)
```

It looks like if the last `JoincolumnOptions` overwrites all previous `JoincolumnOptions`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Article Entity    
@Entity({ name: 'node' })
export class Article {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  public articleId: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ArticleBody)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'articleBodyId' })
  public body: ArticleBody;

  @OneToOne(() => ArticleTitle)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'articleTitleId' })
  public title: ArticleTitle;
}

// Body Entity
@Entity({ name: 'article_body' })
export class ArticleBody {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
  public bodyId: number;

  @Column({ name: 'body_value', nullable: false })
  public bodyValue: string;
}

// Title Entity
@Entity({ name: 'article_title' })
export class ArticleTitle {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
  public titleId: number;

  @Column({ name: 'title_value', nullable: false })
  public titleValue: string;
}
```

**In Article Entity your joinColumn name is same that's why the error is giving**

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work : `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown column 'Article. articleBodyId' in 'field list'`

I have only `articleId` in my field list